# Download a offline version off my website with ajax calls included

Tags: ajax, web, download, static, aem

My client needs a catalog of his website for accessing it when he doesn't have access to the internet. The pages were created using AEM, and he doesn't want to use a local instance to access them. He just wants a folder with all the static files. I'm trying to use httrack, which either returns a 502 HTTP error for the page or the AJAX calls don't work within the offline copy of the page. Do you know some tool to help me?

Comment: Not sure if it helps with AJAX calls, but you may give it a try - https://docs.adobe.com/help/en/experience-manager-64/administering/contentmanagement/page-exporter.html#creating-a-page-exporter-configuration-for-your-site

Comment: What wants your client to reach? Just a quick & dirty copy for internals, or a polished offline catalogue for customers? In any case httrack is a good starting point. Just make sure to grab the content from a publisher with a dispatcher. The AJAX-calls you have to tackle one-by-one anyway. If you need a screenshot of every page (image), you can use Selenium. In case of a real polished catalogue, there are of course much more advanced options (with more effort)